# Azure AD only generates invalid Access Token to use with Microsoft Graph

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, jwt

I've setup an App Registration in Azure Active Directory so that I can access Microsoft OneNote notebooks/sections/pages via the Microsoft Graph.

It's allowing pretty much every Microsoft holding account to login, so I'm using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` as my authorisation endpoint and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` as my token endpoint.
Within the App Registration, I've set API permissions as:

- Notes.Read.All
- offline_access
- openid
- User.Read

I've added a localhost in my Redirect URIs which is listed as "web", so that i can follow the flow through.

The problem I am getting, is that when I eventually receive my access_token, I receive an error when using it as a Bearer Token against: [graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks](http://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "40001",
        "message": "The request does not contain a valid authentication token. Detailed error information: {0}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-10-07T20:37:37",
            "request-id": "c8b0c20e-d096-4fcb-9e97-841b1626537c",
            "client-request-id": "a-uuid"
        }
    }
}
```

So following the flow through, I have something like this:

1. Authenticate via this url

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=99e1fc5a-bl4h-bl4h-bl4h-l0ng3rbl4h&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp&response_type=code&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Notes.Read.All&state=abc&response_mode=query

I'm a little unsure if i'm using the correct scope variables here.  I want to be able to access all of a users OneNote notebooks/sections/pages and read their profile and do things offline,

2. When my user successfully authenticates, the code gets redirected here:

http://localhost/myapp?code=M.R3_BL2.15c2b73a-486c-c0f6-95c1-8432603aa7a4&state=abc

3. I extract the `code` from the querystring and make a POST like:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--form 'code=M.R3_BL2.15c2b73a-486c-c0f6-95c1-8432603aa7a4' \
--form 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--form 'client_id=99e1fc5a-bl4h-bl4h-bl4h-l0ng3rbl4h' \
--form 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Notes.Read.All' \
--form 'client_secret=shhhhASecret'
```

Now this will return me an access_token in some JSON.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid https://graph.microsoft.com/Notes.Read.All",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "EwCQA8l6BAAUO9chh8cJscQLmU+longstring",
    "refresh_token": "M.R3_BL2.CecNbvRse*longstring",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKlongstring"
}
```

However, as stated, this access token doesn't seem to give me access to Microsoft Graph.  I've tried different variations on scopes to use in my requests, but none seem to generate the correct access token.

The code I use for calling Microsoft Graph from node.js

```
const http = require('https');

class OneNote {
constructor(bearer) {
        this.bearer = bearer;
        this.HTTP_CODES = {
            OK: 200,
            Unauthorized: 401
        };
    }

async getNotebooks() {
        const options = this._getOptions();
        options.path += 'notebooks';
        return this._requestData(options)
            .catch((err) => {
                throw err;
            });
    }

_getOptions() {
        return {
            method: 'GET',
            hostname: 'graph.microsoft.com',
            path: '/v1.0/me/onenote/',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.bearer}`
            }
        }
    }

    async _requestData(options) {
        console.log(options)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
                let data = '';
                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    data += d;
                });
                if (res.statusCode === this.HTTP_CODES.Unauthorized) {
                    res.on('end', () => {
                        reject(data);
                    });
                } else {
                    res.on('end', () => {
                        resolve(data);
                    });
                }
            });

            req.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
            req.end();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this access token is OK. Please share your request of calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks` with your access token. And decode your access token in https://jwt.io to see if it has the correct `aud` and `scope`.

Comment: May I know if you  hide the real `code`? Or is your `code` "M.R3_BL2.15c2b73a-486c-c0f6-95c1-8432603aa7a4"? The access token looks different from the common one. What kind of account are you using? O365 account or Microsoft personal account?

Comment: @AllenWu I'm using my personal Microsoft account.  When I use the Microsoft Graph Explorer and copy the access token into jwt.io, it gives an error and doesn't display any data let alone for the ones i've generated myself?  This is my latest real code from authorization: `M.R3_BL2.db535519-c869-054d-df35-64369bfb86fb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use a wrong permission(scope).

Based on [Permissions for listing notebooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), required permissions for personal Microsoft account are `Notes.Create, Notes.Read, Notes.ReadWrite`.

`Notes.Read.All` is not required here.

So please add `Notes.Read` delegated permission in the scope to fix this issue.

Comment: that worked... if I remove Notes.Read.All that would stop a school or work user from being able to read their notes?  So there's no harm in having both permissions, to allow for personal, school and work accounts having access to all their notebooks/sections/pages, right?

Comment: @Jarede Yes. If you remove `Notes.Read.All`, it should not work for work account. But you can assign both `Notes.Read` and `Notes.Read.All` delegated permissions in Azure AD app and use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` in the scope. It will allow for personal, school and work accounts. I think there is no harm. This is one of the ways it works.